# wp_embed_register_handler not working

Tags: embed

I tried the example in this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler but it didn't work. This is my whole code:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    wp_embed_register_handler( 'forbes', '#http://(?:www|video)\.forbes\.com/(?:video/embed/embed\.html|embedvideo/)\?show=([\d]+)&format=frame&height=([\d]+)&width=([\d]+)&video=(.+?)($|&)#i', 'wp_embed_handler_forbes' );
});

function wp_embed_handler_forbes( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr ) {

$embed = sprintf(
        '<iframe src="http://www.forbes.com/video/embed/embed.html?show=%1$s&format=frame&height=%2$s&width=%3$s&video=%4$s&mode=render" width="%3$spx" height="%2$spx" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></iframe>',
        esc_attr($matches[1]),
        esc_attr($matches[2]),
        esc_attr($matches[3]),
        esc_attr($matches[4])
        );

return apply_filters( 'embed_forbes', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: What url are you testing?

Comment: this one 
`http://www.forbes.com/video/5049647995001/`

Comment: that's far away from the accepted url structure in the handler, I guess the Forbes embed service has changed since this example was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the example you posted from the Codex:

```
/**
 * Embed support for Forbes videos
 *
 * Usage Example:
 *
 *     http://www.forbes.com/video/5049647995001/
 */
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    wp_embed_register_handler( 
        'forbes', 
        '#http://www\.forbes\.com/video/([\d]+)/?#i', 
        'wp_embed_handler_forbes' 
    );

} );

function wp_embed_handler_forbes( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
{
    $embed = sprintf(
        '<iframe class="forbes-video" src="https://players.brightcove.net/2097119709001/598f142b-5fda-4057-8ece-b03c43222b3f_default/index.html?videoId=%1$s" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>',
        esc_attr( $matches[1] ) 
     );

    return apply_filters( 'embed_forbes', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```

Currently the `iframe` has a fixed *height* and *width*.

You can hopefully adjust it to your needs, e.g. using the theme's `$content_width` or pass on the height/width information directly from the pasted video url.

**Update:** I added a [warning to the Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler#Examples), until a better example is posted.

Comment: Thanks! Code works on post editor. I can see embed in blog post. 

Currently im using buddypress on my site. When posting the link in activity page it didn't work. According to buddypress(https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/embeds/) they are using the native wp embeds functionality. Could this be a buddypress issue?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. It's been a while since I last used BuddyPress, but if it's working in the post content editor but not in activity pages then it sounds like an issue for BuddyPress. @KelvinMartinLigue

Answer (score 0):

here un example with linkedin

```php
/** linkedin embed
*  example : https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:6704370979721777152
*/
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        wp_embed_register_handler(
            'linkedin',
            '#https://www\.linkedin\.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:([\d]+)/?#i',
            'embed_handler_linkedin'
        );
    }
);

function embed_handler_linkedin( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr ) {

    $embed = sprintf(
        '<iframe src="https://www.linkedin.com/embed/feed/update/urn:li:share:%s" width="500" height="453" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="block__linkedin"></iframe>',
        esc_attr( $matches[1] )
    );

    return apply_filters( 'embed_linkedin', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```