# Embed/Link external web pages into my WordPress blog (Like Facebook grabs Image, Title, and Description)

Tags: links, facebook, embed

I want to create WordPress posts where I embed external pages. As you know, when you paste a link in Facebook, it automatically grabs an image, title, and description. And when someone click it, it directs to the source website. 
I used iframes, but it embeds the complete page. I just want to show it as it appears in Facebook shares. I want to aggregate news from around the web on my homepage. If I can add the functionality of user voting on the stories, it would be an added advantage. 
PS: I am not a programmer. [image: Example]

Comment: Thank you very much @jgraup. You answer explains it very well. I have checked the WrodPress codex for embeds. It is the functionality I am looking for. But I want it for every website, not only some specific websites. And thanks for your effort to write code. However, I am not able to test it because I do not have any programming knowledge. For the time being, I am evaluating  Embed Link ShortCode Plugin by Fermin Molina. Although, a custom solution would be a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be describing [embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) which WordPress supports. On https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds you'll find a long list of currently supported embeds simply based on the URLs added in your editor.

For the embed to work, it's required to be on a single line with a space above and below. And generally they are constructed during [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter.

To test which embeds you currently support, you can force an embed to transform from a url using [`wp_oembed_get($url)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get).

There are two methods you can use to add support for embeds that aren't currently included.

- For non-oEmbed sites - [`wp_embed_register_handler( $id, $regex, $callback, $priority )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler)
- For oEmbed-enabled sites - [`wp_oembed_add_provider( $format, $provider, $regex )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider).

In the case a site is not included, you may need to code the regular expression required to transform a URL to an Embed. But after that it'll work like magic.

An example given for a custom embed on non-supported oEmbed site (modified from [`@birgire`'s answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/238351/84219)):

```
/**
 * Embed support for Forbes videos
 *
 * Usage Example:
 *
 *     http://www.forbes.com/video/5049647995001/
 */
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    wp_embed_register_handler(
        'forbes',
        '#http://www\.forbes\.com/video/([\d]+)/?#i',
        'wp_embed_handler_forbes'
    );

} );

function wp_embed_handler_forbes( $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr )
{
    // construct the video embed

    $embed = sprintf(
        '<iframe class="forbes-video" src="https://players.brightcove.net/2097119709001/598f142b-5fda-4057-8ece-b03c43222b3f_default/index.html?videoId=%1$s" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>',
        esc_attr( $matches[1] )
    );

    // pull information from the page

    $str = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url));
    preg_match_all('/<head>(?:[^<]+)<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/', $str, $matches);
    $title = @$matches[1][0];
    preg_match_all('/<meta name="description" itemprop="description" content="([^"]+)"/', $str, $matches);
    $description = @$matches[1][0];
    preg_match_all('/<meta property="og:image" content="([^"]+)"/', $str, $matches);
    $image = @$matches[1][0];

    // prepend extra info

    $embed = sprintf('<a href="%s" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" ><img src="%s"><h1>%s</h1></a><p>%s</p>%s', $url, $image, $title, $description, $embed);

    return apply_filters( 'embed_forbes', $embed, $matches, $attr, $url, $rawattr );
}
```

Sample with:

```
http://www.forbes.com/video/5049647995001/

http://www.forbes.com/video/5037500512001/

http://www.forbes.com/video/4284088649001/

http://www.forbes.com/video/5046852474001/
```

While this example specifically uses an `iframe` you can construct anything from the url. It takes extra time but you, in theory, could pull the URL and scrape the details for a customize visual.

For Facebook, they use a service http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/  to cache the scraped content, then serve cached data. That's why sometimes the first share of a page takes a while to show up. If you want to speed up this process, you would have a mechanism to cache the content to be served.

Comment: ps: I just wanted to mention that the Forbes example from the Codex doesn't work as is, though it shows how to setup such an handler. It has caused some [confusion](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238330/wp-embed-register-handler-not-working), but I found a new iframe source for it [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/238330/26350), until they change it again ;-)

Comment: Thanks @birgire. I think a while back I may have seen an issue with it. Maybe I'll harass someone at WordCamp US this year to change it on the spot.

Comment: I added a warning to that Codex example, until a better example is posted ;-)

Comment: I think you should have made it neon and flashing!

Comment: yes or maybe as a very annoying popup ad ;-)

Comment: @birgire - added some mods to your version and included here.

Comment: Thank you so much @jgraup. I understand your instructions; although, I would not try to add any code to my website as I have no programming knowledge. I am trying Embed Link ShortCode Plugin by Fermin Molina. The plugin tries to do the same. I hope I will be able to get by unless I get the assistance of a programmer who can do it according to my specific requirements. If anyone has an idea to do it in a better way (without programming knowledge), I would be thankful.